# How can I get audience performance report data via the Google Adwords API?

Tags: google-ads, api, reporting

I can get `Keywords Performance Report`, `Campaign Performance Report` and so on.

E.g. The xml data of `Keywords Performance Report`:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
    <report-name name='Keywords Performance Report'/>
    <date-range date='All Time'/>
    <table>
        <row keywordID='15444305302' adGroupID='58698790018' adGroup='dry cleaners near me' adGroupState='enabled' campaignID='1474036973' campaign='Martinizing - Huntingdon' keyword='dry cleaners near me' keywordState='enabled' maxCPC='auto: 12280000' firstPageCPC='2190000' topOfPageCPC='2440000' clicks='0' impressions='9' ctr='0.00%' cost='0' conversions='0.00' avgCPC='0' avgPosition='1.4'/>
    </table>
</report>
```

Now, I try to get `Audience Performance Report`, but there is no `row` in the report:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' standalone='yes'?>
<report>
    <report-name name='Audience Performance Report'/>
    <date-range date='All Time'/>
</report>
```

As you can see, I set the date range to `All Time`.This is my `selector` of report definition.

```
{
    "selector": {
        "fields": [
            "Id",
            "CampaignId",
            "CampaignName",
            "Criteria",
            "Clicks",
            "Impressions",
            "Cost",
            "Conversions"
        ]
    }
}
```

I had published a lot of campaigns, adGroups, ads. So, what conditions do I have to meet for the published campaigns, adGroups, ads so that I can get  `row` xml data of `Audience Performance Report`?